# List of getmail options

Tags: getmail

In my `.getmailrc` I have

```
[options]
delete = true
```

I assume there are more such options.  Where can I find a list with
explanations?  (Using `SimpleIMAPSSLRetriever`, if it matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/configuration.html) describes the configuration syntax and options in detail. The linked page describes version 5; the version you have installed probably includes the applicable documentation.